# Chromecast continously broadcasts as unsecured AP after setup

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, chromecast

I set up my Chromecast a few weeks ago and everything has been going well. Over the weekend as I was connecting a new device to my network, I noticed that my Chromecast was broadcasting an open network with the name I had given it. When I tried connecting to it, it said I would not be able to access the internet using this network, but it would still allow the connection.

I am quite concerned as I know for the initial setup the Chromecast creates the unsecured network before affiliating with my network, so why is it still broadcasting like this? [This thread on the Google forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/chromecast/unsecured$20wifi$20network%7Csort:relevance/chromecast/9bhh5G0ZnXM) seems to confirm what I've noticed, and there does not seem to be a proper answer. I was having line issues last week, so the router was turned on and off several times, but if I check the Chromecast on my TV, it appears connected to my network and everything is normal.

Also, the TV it is connected to is kept switched off at the plug, so according to [this post](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chromecast/9bhh5G0ZnXM/4dmzRmI8O1EJ) further down the thread, the Chromecast would be broadcasting the unsecured network everytime the TV is switched on. My question is, why is the Chromecast broadcasting when it is already affiliated with my home network?

Answer (score 0):

Its the guest mode being turned on.
See here
http://www.vexperienced.co.uk/2015/07/02/chromecast-causing-wifi-interference-resolved/